# Add ClickHandler to html class

Tags: html, gwt, dom

I need to add ClickHandlers to many checkboxes (>4000), and it's doing for 40 sec. 
How can I add handler to all elements in html class?

now:

```
 ChckBoxHandler cbh = new ChckBoxHandler();
SimpleCheckBox.wrap(DOM.getElementById("chbid" + ID)).addClickHandler(cbh);
```

i want:

```
DOM.getElementsByClass("chkboxes").addClickHandler(cbh);
```

Comment: 4000 checkboxes in one page?

Comment: i think event delegation will be a be a much better solution, this way you can attach only one event Handler on the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a simple solution:

Why don't you add a click handler to the parent widget (the html panel? or whatever panel you are using) and check for clicks.

Whenever a click is done you can then loop through your checkboxes and see which one has a checked state.

Comment: it's table, and i also have links on rows. If I click on link - handler will activate? it's bad for me

Comment: This pretty nearly the GWT version of @Ibu's solution - just as in that case, you must filter to see which thing was actually clicked. JQuery does some of that filtering for you, and this is pretty easy to do in GWT - get the target of the event, ask it what it is (`input` vs `a`) or what its `class` or `name` attribute is - some way to distinguish it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a lot of elements in your page (4000 in your case), it is not a good idea to assigned an event to every single one of them. It will hurt performance. Instead you can use event delegation which consist of (in case of a click) assigning an event to the parent element and check which of the child element was clicked and run the code for it

Here is a very good tutorial of how it works by David Walsh, creator of jsfiddle.net.

[How JavaScript Event Delegation Works](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

If you were to use jQuery there is a very simple method that takes care of that for you.

[jQuery .live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: wants to stay in gwt, but if there is no another solution - to do just that, thanks